# Using Microsoft Flow to check if an email has been sent client-side via the desktop Outlook 365 app

Tags: office365, power-automate

Is it possible to create a new Flow which is able to detect if an email has been sent when a user clicks send on their `desktop` Outlook 365?

To be specific, I'm not interested in checking on exchange if the email has been sent, I need the check to happen before that on client-side desktop app level.

Comment: In flow what is the app you are trying to trigger an action ?

Comment: @RagavanRajan Trying to trigger flow from Outlook 365 Desktop, not Outllok 365 Webapp.  Basically, want to trigger a flow before the email is detected by exchange.  I am assuming this is not possible without writing an Outlook 365 Desktop plugin to intercept the email before it is sent off to exchange?

Comment: That's my understanding too. Exchange is the layer which will trigger first before going to any type of client app.